# Query with Unique Combination and other Parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in Google Sheets, Let's say the named sheet is Sheet 10 and Sheet 11. In Sheet 10, I have data in the range `Sheet 10'!A:E` as pictured below:

[image]

Then in Sheet 11, I have data in the range `Sheet 11'!A:E` as pictured below:
[image]

In Sheet 11 column E, i would like to query data values from Sheet 10 (only column E) by unique combination of `ID Primary`, `Time`, `Date`, and `Production`.

Below is an example of my expected output based on the sample data above.

[image]

Before that, i have created formula but it not worked. Following my formula:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet 10'!A2:E; "SELECT E WHERE A = '"&A2&"' AND B = '"&B2&"' AND C = '"&TEXT(C2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND D = '"&D2&"' "; 0))
```

For information Column B and E in Sheet 10, i changed format `time` to text ("HH:MM").

Does anyone know how the formula to solve this problem? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947) where the search_key and column are the concatenated values:

Enter the following formula in `Sheet11!E2` after clearing everything in `E2:E`:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   XLOOKUP(
     A2:A & B2:B & C2:C & D2:D,
     Sheet10!A2:A & Sheet10!B2:B & Sheet10!C2:C & Sheet10!D2:D,
     Sheet10!E2:E,))
```